# Split a list of dataframes into separate dataframes

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have several dataframes stored in a list of lists. I need to save each one separatelly, as a dataframe or tibble, keeping the same name stored in the original list. I've tried many ways, with no sucess at all.

```
Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)
df1<- data.frame(Name, Age)


Name <- c("Carter", "Bill", "Oliver")
Age <- c(20, 40, 32)
df2<- data.frame(Name, Age)


Name <- c("Karin", "Victor", "Tara")
Age <- c(30, 40, 10)
df3<- data.frame(Name, Age)

df_names<-c("January", "February", "March")

list_of_dataframes<- list(df1, df2, df3)
 
names(list_of_dataframes)<- df_names
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Try `list2env(list_of_dataframes, .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: @akrun it worked ! Genius!